# Dell Inspiron 15 5000 series wont boot or boot any media

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, boot, laptop, bios

I am a computer technician working out of a local shop and we had this laptop come in with a perplexing issue. I will go ahead and run down what I've tried.

Bios:
Tried disabling secure boot, enabling legacy boot and legacy options.
After such I tried loading both Windows 10 DVD as well as a burned Windows 10 ISO on USB flash drive (Tried both Windows creation tool and rufus).

Both USB and DVD media go to a screen with Dell logo and circle dots loading symbol. Looks like the CPU light gets active for a bit and then just stops. Everything stays loading for infinite time. It did this before I changed settings in bios as well.

Three restarts:
Tried doing three restarts in a row to launch the troubleshooting screen. It would just go to "Preparing Automatic Repair" and stay there for a long time.. over night even.

Then I tried setting everything back to defaults and trying to just boot the hard drive. Secure boot enabled, UEFI set, default keys in place. Now on each start I get either:
1. Dell logo with swirling dots.
2. Dell Logo with Preparing Automatic Repair.

Tried chkdsk on existing hard drive.
Tried diagnostic for hardware: 100% pass.
Tried Dell Restore & Backup: Infinite loading screen.

Is the BIOS borked?
I've been working on this for a solid week to no avail. Going a little crazy.

Any input on this would be greatly appreciated. I really have no idea where to go from here as I've scoured the internet and have tried every troubleshooting concept I've learned in the past 10 years.

**I also tried static discharge, removing battery and AC and holding power for 60 seconds. Also updated Bios to one newer iteration supporting Windows 10.

Comment: Dell Laptop right? Can you go to the Boot Options (F12) and if you're worried about problematic BIOS - can you update it to the latest? What are you trying to do exactly? Reinstalling it?

Comment: Yes Dell Inspiron. I updated the Bios from A07 to A08 which was ironically to bring support for Windows 10. I was trying to repair existing install of 10, now trying to reinstall as that didn't work.

Comment: So you can't even reinstall W10 on it? If so, could it boot from any linux live cd?

Comment: Correct, Windows 10 media whether USB or DVD leads to trailing dots loading screen. Good idea! I will try that today.

Comment: Guys... Could liquid damage cause everything to function fine (diagnostics, hard drive) except boot? I opened laptop and see spots of sticky dried coke under keyboard, next to the hard drive mount and under battery. Heavy corrosion under keboard.

Comment: With the diagnostics you had, I would say it is certified dead. The coke may well have corroded the motherboard. [Top-10 Liquid Spills That Kill Laptop Computers](http://www.sewelltech.com/top-10-liquid-spills-kill-laptop-computers/)